# ORA-00917 Missing Comma, but it isn't missing?

Tags: oracle, database-administration, ora-00917

Doing some Oracle DBA homework and I've looked at several posts about the 00917 error, but I'm just doing a simple INSERT.  I can't seem to see where I'm missing a comma or a parenthesis.  Any help?

```
INSERT INTO copy_f_orders 
(ORDER_NUMBER, TO_DATE(ORDER_DATE, 'mm-dd-RRRR'), ORDER_TOTAL, CUST_ID, STAFF_ID)
VALUES (5691, '09-23-2004', 145.98, 225, 12);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use function call in column list:

```
INSERT INTO copy_f_orders(ORDER_NUMBER, ORDER_DATE, ORDER_TOTAL, CUST_ID, STAFF_ID)
VALUES (5691, '09-23-2004', 145.98, 225, 12);
```

If you need call it in values:

```
INSERT INTO copy_f_orders(ORDER_NUMBER, ORDER_DATE, ORDER_TOTAL, CUST_ID, STAFF_ID)
VALUES (5691, TO_DATE('09-23-2004', 'mm-dd-RRRR'), 145.98, 225, 12);
```

Comment: Weird...this is the direct copy/paste from the Oracle training materials:

    Inserting Specific Date Values (cont.)
    Similarly, if we want to INSERT a row with a non-default format for a date column, we must use the TO_DATE function to convert the date value (a character string) to a date.
    INSERT INTO f_staffs
    (first_name, TO_DATE(birthdate, 'Month fmDD, RRRR')
    VALUES
    (‘Sue’, ‘July 1, 1980’);

Comment: @TheDoc Please provide link

Comment: @TheDoc You mean the Oracle online documentation?

Comment: The iLearning Oracle Academy training info.  I'm going through that right now.

Comment: @TheDoc Could you provide screenshoot, it is very interesting

Comment: spot-on, lad2025 (as is @RoyParuchuri below).  The INSERT works fine with the TO_DATE in the VALUES clause.  Thanks guys!  Still confusing why the documentation written in 2013 would be wrong on syntax...

Comment: @TheDoc Not only that, see what kind of quote they use `’` and not `'`

Comment: @TheDoc If you can please let them know they have bugs in examples.

Comment: @lad2025 I'll let them know if I can figure out how!  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO copy_f_orders 
(ORDER_NUMBER, TO_DATE(ORDER_DATE, 'mm-dd-RRRR'), ORDER_TOTAL, CUST_ID, STAFF_ID)
VALUES (5691, '09-23-2004', 145.98, 225, 12);
```

It should be

```
INSERT INTO copy_f_orders 
(ORDER_NUMBER, ORDER_DATE, ORDER_TOTAL, CUST_ID, STAFF_ID)
VALUES (5691, TO_DATE('09-23-2004', 'mm-dd-RRRR'), 145.98, 225, 12);
```

No point using TO_DATE functions on columns, Hope it makes sense.

Comment: You're missing the brackets around the list of columns to be inserted into in your 2nd query. It would error, as is!

Comment: Thanks, @Roy Paruchuri.  Got the same response above, but the Oracle iLearning Academy documentation says clearly, Similarly, if we want to INSERT a row with a non-default format for a date column, we must use the TO_DATE function to convert the date value (a character string) to a date. INSERT INTO f_staffs (first_name, TO_DATE(birthdate, 'Month fmDD, RRRR') VALUES (‘Sue’, ‘July 1, 1980’);

However, I tried it with the function in the VALUES clause and everything works fine.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the correction guys, This is strange to see oracle documentation states that, this is out of experience that I updated your query.

Comment: @RoyParuchuri just fyi; if you're adding code to your answers/questions, you should make sure you format it as code, so that it displays in a readable format. To do this for code in a block, either make sure that every row starts with 4 spaces, or highlight the text and click on the "{}" button in the editor toolbar. If it's a code snippet, such as `select...` then you can use the backtick (`) before and after the snippet to get it correctly formatted. This last bit works even in comments. *{:-)

Comment: Thanks @Boneist  for your feedback

Answer (score -1):

```
("INSERT INTO copy_f_orders 
(ORDER_NUMBER, TO_DATE(ORDER_DATE, 'mm-dd-RRRR'), ORDER_TOTAL, CUST_ID, STAFF_ID)
VALUES (5691, '09-23-2004', 145.98, 225, 12)");
```

Comment: add some real text with answer